# Combine files and store in string

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.5.x/Bucket#combine

clearly states that the second parameter of combine could be

> (string or File)
>
> The file you would like the source files combined into.

However when I do like the code below:

```
var logBucket = storage.bucket(projectId);

var sources = [
   logBucket.file(file1),
   logBucket.file(file2)
];

let myString;

logBucket.combine(sources, myString);

console.log(myString);
```

I expect to get the two combined sources in myString but I get the error:

> (node:39248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: A destination
>   file must be specified.
>       at Bucket.combine (/Users/joakimmansson/Repo/icm-coworker-tool/server/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:627:19)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the documentation of the combine API that you referenced, we see that the second parameter of the function is defined as:

```
destination (string or File) - The file you would like the source files combined into.
```

What destination specified will always be a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) Object (a file) that will be populated with the combined content of the input sources.  Where the documentation says that `destination` can be a `string` or a `File` that refers to the *identity* of the target GCS object.  This means that one can supply either a File object or the string name of a File Object that will then be created.  I have the suspicion that you were maybe thinking that this would somehow be a returned parameter that would be a string value containing the concatenation of the source files.